# JQuery body does not move all elements?

Tags: jquery

I am just learning jQuery and have come across an example I do not fully understand.

Here is the code:

```
var main = function(){
    $('.icon-menu').click(function(){
        $('.menu').animate({left:'0px'},200)     //move menu in
        $('body').animate({left:'285px'},200)    //shift all content
    })
}

$(document).ready(main)
```

Obviously, this is to make a menu slide in from the left side of the page.

The menu is currently at `left:-285px;` and gets moved into view. However, on the second command, I do not understand why shifting the `$('body')` does not also shift the menu as well? (it is part of the body)

Thank you very much!

ps: This example is here on [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-zmn0b/0/1?content_from=make-an-interactive-website%3Ayour-first-program)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu has `position: fixed` which means its position is relative to the window, not the body content.

See here for more details on positioning: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: WOW, how could I have missed that! perfect, Thanks!

Comment: needed to wait 10 minutes :p you answered too fast!